# opengles put bitmap outside the sphere

Tags: android, opengl-es

i want to put the texture out the sphere,i search some link

https://github.com/kibotu/net.gtamps/blob/refactoring3d/android/graphic/src/net/gtamps/android/renderer/graph/scene/primitives/Sphere.java

https://github.com/ejeinc/RajawaliCardboardExample

all are put the texture inside of the sphere. how to do this

i do a texture inside of the sphere

```
public class SphereModel {
// Init variable value
private final int INVALID_STATE = -1;
int mProgram = INVALID_STATE;
int muMVPMatrixHandle = -1;
int muMMatrixHandle = -1;// 
int maCameraHandle = -1; // 
int maPositionHandle = -1; // 
int maNormalHandle = -1; //
int maTexCoorHandle = -1; // 
int maSunLightLocationHandle = -1;
int uDayTexHandle = -1;
String mVertexShader;
String mFragmentShader;
FloatBuffer mVertexBuffer;
FloatBuffer mTexCoorBuffer;
int vCount = 0;

float[] mvpM = new float[16];
float[] mM = new float[16];




public SphereModel(Resources r, float radius) {

    initVertexData(radius);

    initShader(r);

    Matrix.setIdentityM(mvpM, 0);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mM, 0);

    Matrix.translateM(mM, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}


public void initVertexData(float r) {
    // ================begin============================
    final float UNIT_SIZE = 0.5f;
    ArrayList<Float> alVertix = new ArrayList<Float>();
    final float angleSpan = 10f;
    for (float vAngle = 90; vAngle > -90; vAngle = vAngle - angleSpan) {
        for (float hAngle = 360; hAngle > 0; hAngle = hAngle - angleSpan) {

            double xozLength = r * UNIT_SIZE
                    * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(vAngle));
            float x1 = (float) (xozLength * Math
                    .cos(Math.toRadians(hAngle)));
            float z1 = (float) (xozLength * Math
                    .sin(Math.toRadians(hAngle)));
            float y1 = (float) (r * UNIT_SIZE * Math.sin(Math
                    .toRadians(vAngle)));

            xozLength = r * UNIT_SIZE
                    * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(vAngle - angleSpan));
            float x2 = (float) (xozLength * Math
                    .cos(Math.toRadians(hAngle)));
            float z2 = (float) (xozLength * Math
                    .sin(Math.toRadians(hAngle)));
            float y2 = (float) (r * UNIT_SIZE * Math.sin(Math
                    .toRadians(vAngle - angleSpan)));

            xozLength = r * UNIT_SIZE
                    * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(vAngle - angleSpan));
            float x3 = (float) (xozLength * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(hAngle
                    - angleSpan)));
            float z3 = (float) (xozLength * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(hAngle
                    - angleSpan)));
            float y3 = (float) (r * UNIT_SIZE * Math.sin(Math
                    .toRadians(vAngle - angleSpan)));

            xozLength = r * UNIT_SIZE * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(vAngle));
            float x4 = (float) (xozLength * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(hAngle
                    - angleSpan)));
            float z4 = (float) (xozLength * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(hAngle
                    - angleSpan)));
            float y4 = (float) (r * UNIT_SIZE * Math.sin(Math
                    .toRadians(vAngle)));

            alVertix.add(x1);
            alVertix.add(y1);
            alVertix.add(z1);
            alVertix.add(x2);
            alVertix.add(y2);
            alVertix.add(z2);
            alVertix.add(x4);
            alVertix.add(y4);
            alVertix.add(z4);

            alVertix.add(x4);
            alVertix.add(y4);
            alVertix.add(z4);
            alVertix.add(x2);
            alVertix.add(y2);
            alVertix.add(z2);
            alVertix.add(x3);
            alVertix.add(y3);
            alVertix.add(z3);
        }
    }
    vCount = alVertix.size() / 3;

    float vertices[] = new float[vCount * 3];
    for (int i = 0; i < alVertix.size(); i++) {
        vertices[i] = alVertix.get(i);
    }

    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    mVertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
    mVertexBuffer.put(vertices);
    mVertexBuffer.position(0);

    float[] texCoor = generateTexCoor(
            (int) (360 / angleSpan), 
            (int) (180 / angleSpan) 
    );
    ByteBuffer llbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texCoor.length * 4);
    llbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    mTexCoorBuffer = llbb.asFloatBuffer();
    mTexCoorBuffer.put(texCoor);
    mTexCoorBuffer.position(0);
}

public void initShader(Resources r) { 

    mVertexShader = ShaderUtil.loadFromAssetsFile("vertex_tex_f.sh", r);
    ShaderUtil.checkGlError("==ss==");

    mFragmentShader = ShaderUtil.loadFromAssetsFile("frag_tex_f.sh", r);

    ShaderUtil.checkGlError("==ss==");
    mProgram = ShaderUtil.createProgram(mVertexShader, mFragmentShader);

    maPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aPosition");

    maTexCoorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aTexCoor");

    muMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
}

public void drawSelf(Eye transform, int textureId) {

    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);


    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);
    GLES20.glFrontFace(GLES20.GL_CW);




    if(ThunderConstant.MODE_CHOICE==1){

        if(ThunderConstant.TYPE_CHOICE==0){
            Matrix.setLookAtM(mM, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0f, 0f, -10f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
        }else if(ThunderConstant.TYPE_CHOICE==1){
            Matrix.setLookAtM(mM, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0f, 0f, -10f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
            Matrix.translateM(mM, 0, 0, -1.5f, 0);
        }else if(ThunderConstant.TYPE_CHOICE==2){

        }
    }else{

        if(ThunderConstant.TYPE_CHOICE==0){
            Matrix.setLookAtM(mM, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0f, 0f, -10f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
        }else if(ThunderConstant.TYPE_CHOICE==1){
            Matrix.setLookAtM(mM, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0f, 0f, -10f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
            Matrix.translateM(mM, 0, 0, -1.5f, 0);
        }else if(ThunderConstant.TYPE_CHOICE==2){

        }

    }



    Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpM, 0, transform.getEyeView(), 0, mM, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpM, 0, transform.getPerspective(0.1f, 200f), 0, mvpM, 0);

    if(PanoramaImageActivityNormalMode.isGestureControl){
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false,
                MatrixState.getFinalMatrixOfFullImage(transform), 0);
    }else{
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpM, 0);
    }


    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(

            maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * 4,
            mVertexBuffer);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(

            maTexCoorHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 2 * 4,
            mTexCoorBuffer);

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);


    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTexCoorHandle);
    // GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maNormalHandle);

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vCount);
}





public float[] generateTexCoor(int bw, int bh) {
    float[] result = new float[bw * bh * 6 * 2];
    // float sizew=1.0f/bw;
    // float sizeh=1.0f/bh;
    float sizew = 1.0f / bw;
    float sizeh = 1.0f / bh;
    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < bh; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < bw; j++) {

            float s = 1 - j * sizew;
            float t = i * sizeh;

            result[c++] = s;
            result[c++] = t;

            result[c++] = s;
            result[c++] = t + sizeh;

            result[c++] = s - sizew;
            result[c++] = t;

            //
            result[c++] = s - sizew;
            result[c++] = t;

            result[c++] = s;
            result[c++] = t + sizeh;

            result[c++] = s - sizew;
            result[c++] = t + sizeh;
        }
    }
    return result;

}

/**
 * recycle resource
 */
public void recyleRecource() {
    if (mProgram != INVALID_STATE) {
        GLES20.glDeleteProgram(mProgram);
        mProgram = INVALID_STATE;
    }
}
```

}

how to modify it make the texture inside of the sphere

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach (but not recommended) is to remove back face culling. [See Here](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glCullFace.xml)

The real problem is in how your texture coordinates and surface normals are represented. Think about which side of the sphere is the front face and which is the back face. If you want the texture on the outside of the sphere then the winding order, surface normals, and texture coordinates need to reflect that.

Given the code sample you provided, you need to change the winding order and U,V in this code,

```
          for (c = 0; c <= stacks; c++) {
            float u = (float) c / (float) stacks; // [0,1]
            float theta2 = u * (float) (Math.PI * 2f); // [0,2PI]
            pos.set(n);
            pos.rotateY(theta2);

            posFull.set(pos);
            posFull.mulInPlace(dimension.x);

            mesh.vertices.addVertex(posFull.x, posFull.y, posFull.z, pos.x, pos.y, pos.z, emissive.r, emissive.g, emissive.b, emissive.a, u, v);
        }
```

Imagine the triangles being created by this code during 'mesh.vertices.addVertex'. For each set of three vertices (each triangle), you need to invert the winding order so that the triangles are flipped to render to the outside. Depending on the texture you use, you may also need to flip the U,V coordinates passed in.

**EDIT**
I don't have an editor handy to prove it but you may simply need to reverse the for loop (iterate the for loop backwards ) and add the vertices in reverse order to reverse the winding.

Something like

```
for (c = stacks-1; c >= 0; --c) {
    ...
}
```